# jquery datePicker fire textchange event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker, servercontrols

i create server  control with jquery datepicker , which i initial in my render method.
in the textbox i set autopostback and add custom event to fire on textchanged
this is the server side :

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        _txtCalender = new TextBox();
        _txtCalender.ID = "_txtCalender" + this.ID;
        _txtCalender.ReadOnly = true;
        _txtCalender.AutoPostBack = true;
        _txtCalender.TextChanged += new EventHandler(_txtCalender_TextChanged); 
        Controls.Add(_txtCalender);              
 }

//Raised when the select Change
    public event EventHandler SelectionDateChanged
    {
        add
        {
            Events.AddHandler(eventSelectedChange, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            Events.RemoveHandler(eventSelectedChange, value);
        }
    }

    private void _OnSelectedChange(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnSelectedChange(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    //The method that raises the select Change event.
    protected void OnSelectedChange(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler selectedChangeHandler = (EventHandler)Events[eventSelectedChange];

        if (selectedChangeHandler != null)
            selectedChangeHandler(this, e);
    }
```

on the client side of i set the datepicker select property like that:

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        try {
            window.console && console.log($(hiddenFld).val()); 

            inst.input.val($(hiddenFld).val()); 
            inst.input.trigger('change');

        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }
```

when i select date it create postback but it not getting in to the OnTextChanged
what did i missed?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand it well

Comment: if im not set the trigger to change it doesnt do any postback, i guess the change event wont fire unless ill call it from the datepicker onSelect , but it doesnt fire the server event of textChanged .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is solved.
i hope it could help someone ,

when i took this line out:

```
_txtCalender.ReadOnly = true;
```

it works and i didnt have to add the trigger onSelect.
i just delete those line from my javascript:

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {  
    try {  
        window.console && console.log($(hiddenFld).val());   

        inst.input.val($(hiddenFld).val());   
        inst.input.trigger('change');  

    }  
    catch (err) {  
        alert(err);  
    }  
}
```